# What was the first use of the Star Trek Formula in TV, Books, Movies, or Radio?

Tags: story-identification

I saw this on TV when I was a kid. The basic idea seemed directly lifted from the movie, *Forbidden Planet*. The Leslie Nielsen captain character was played by a good looking, charismatic actor, and the cerebral Warren Stevens doctor character was covered by a cerebral second officer character and a conscience-driven doctor character. The ship was run like a large naval vessel, but traveled around the galaxy at super-luminal speeds. Some of the episodes were similar plot-wise to the movie in that the ship would visit a planet inhabited solely by a Walter Pidgeon type loner character and a beautiful young woman (Anne Francis) character.

Did the concept of *StarTrek* originate from *Forbidden Planet* or was *Forbidden Planet* itself derivative of an earlier SF story (book, short story, movie, or other form)?

Comment: Where did you watch ? US, Canada, UK, other ? Was a teen in the 60s (US) and watched any sci fi that was on. Don't recall anything like this. Would love to know what it was. Let's see what the community can do.

Comment: Star Trek? Although, is "charismatic" accurate for William Shatner?

Comment: I initially took this seriously but am now wondering if our legs are being pulled. I never mentioned Star Trek in prior comment since it's so obvious. Is this a genuine question Bob ? Sure sounds like Star Trek and can't believe you wouldn't know that.

Comment: Oh my god, I think *Galaxy Quest* might be based off this same series! We must track it down!

Comment: @HorusKol - By "charismatic" I mean that the captain's face was shown to be glowing in close-ups in some of the episodes... probably with some kind of soft light effect.

Comment: @Stan - Perhaps you are over-estimating my intellect.

Comment: @BobBrandt I notice you haven't answered 'Is this a genuine question' so I ask it again. Is the question serious and is it a series other than Star Trek. As far as your intellect, if your profile is truthful, you're no dummy.

Comment: @Stan - The answer is indeed Star Trek. I am sure Roddenberry was influenced by *Forbidden Planet*, although I wonder if he might have been involved with the movie in some way. Perhaps someone here has some insight on such an origin. (My profile is real.) You were lucky to have seen the series in the 60s. My parents would not let me because my mother saw how some of the women were dressed, so I discovered it from reruns in the 70s.

Comment: Forbidden Planet influence most sci-fi shows and movies set in outer space from the sixties onward. It is impossible to overstate its influence.

Comment: @BobBrandt So was this a trick question? Since you obviously knew the answer beforehand.

Comment: I'm VTC this. I don't believe it is asked in good faith.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not asked in good faith. Virtually no one with any 20th century cultural awareness could provide so much detail and not know the answer.

Comment: @JohnO Agreed. And then to have evaded directly answering my question first time I asked. Shame.

Comment: @Stan - I had no idea you were offended. I thought I had answered your question in a friendly way, and in a way that clarified the intent of the question. I am not ashamed at asking a stimulating and insightful question, and am amazed to see it get down voted. Is this issue of interest to nobody on this site? This is certainly more serious and interesting than the color of Harry Potter's toothbrush. Given the response I have received her until now, I will still be left to wonder about the relationship between Star Trek and Forbidden Planet, without any input form readers of this site.

Comment: First, you didn't answer the first time I asked if it was a serious question. Second, the originally posted question before editing appeared to ask for the name of the series. If what you wanted to know what's now the second paragraph in the edited question, why not simply have asked that.

Comment: @BobBrandt Rather than try to salvage this question by editing it and turning it into a brand new one, I recommend just reverting it back to the original version, let it stay closed, and ask a brand new one, if you like, about the "Star Trek formula" that you are trying to ask about now.  Your new question is completely different from your original question, and if you ask a new one instead of editing this one, it will start at 0 votes, rather than a negative score.

Comment: @BenMiller - Thanks for the suggestion, Ben. However, it now seems clear the question is not welcome on this site, and it is doubtful that it will receive any more insight than has already been offered.

Comment: @BobBrandt Humor is not always well received on Stack Exchange.  But you've raised several other questions that MIGHT be better received: Was Star Trek influenced by previous works?  Was Roddenberry involved in the production of Forbidden Planet?  How has Forbidden Planet influenced future works?  These are all potential questions that could be asked on the site.  But edit this question and revert it back to its original form, then ask the new questions.

Comment: Want to add my final comment on this after having read Ben's last comments since I'm unsure he's clear on why this was problematic.  The question as originally posed had title '1960's TV series about a military space ship exploring the galaxy'. Question stated seen as a kid, looked like directly lifted from 'Forbidden Planet', colorful character descriptions and ended with 'This is driving me crazy since it is deeply embedded in my psyche.'

Comment: No indication at all that it was anything other than a question for a TV series identification.   I didn't initially imagine that it was 'Star Trek' since (as JohnO pointed out) anyone with 20th century cultural awareness would know that'.  I thought 'WOW - there was this really neat series in the 60's that I never saw when on !  Let's find out what it was'.  Only later (after having to ask the question twice) was it revealed that the questioner knew it was Star Trek right from the beginning.

Comment: Later we see that what was really desired was to know if Star Trek had it's roots in Forbidden Planet and / or was Forbidden Planet based on some earlier work.  All this ado (and associated community negativity) would have been avoided if that question had simply been asked to begin with.  As @BenMiller states, I think that's a very viable question and WOULD BE well received as a new question without the historical baggage of this one.  I hope the questioner will continue to contribute and resubmit.

Comment: OOPs - Should have said "Bob's" last comment not Ben's.  My bad.

Answer (score 4):

The show you are thinking about is called [Star Trek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_The_Original_Series), a short-lived television series from the late 1960s.  It's not surprising that you can't remember it; it was not nearly as famous as a science fiction series that came a year earlier called [My Mother the Car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Mother_The_Car), commonly referred to by cult fan clubs as MMTC.  MMTC was a groundbreaking series that was a generation ahead of its time, pioneering the science fiction concept of vehicle AI that would be used later in [Knight Rider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_Rider_%281982_TV_series%29).  Somehow, Star Trek was able to last a measly 2 seasons longer than MMTC before getting cancelled.

Comment: I can't wait for MMTCcon 2014!